# Jasmine jQuery: loadFixtures() "undefined"?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

My Set-up

1. Win7/64bit
2. Wamp Server
3. SublimeText 2

What I did...

1. Loaded jasmine via ruby *(jasmine init)*
2. Ran rake *(rake jasmine)*
3. deleted all the default public javascripts, spec files and helper files.
4. added jquery and jasmine-jquery to the "helpers" directory
5. Opened a browser, fired up liveReload and ran the following tests...

... of which, only "**readFixtures()**" passed. All others fail. wtf? Please advise!

"**readFixtures()**" test works perfectly...

```
describe("test read fixtures", function() {
    it("should be able to read fixtures", function() {
        // expect(readFixtures()).toBeDefined();
        expect(readFixtures()).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

"**loadFixtures()**" test returns "Expected undefined to be defined."

```
describe("test load fixtures", function() {
    it("should be able to load fixtures", function() {
        // expect(loadFixtures()).toBeDefined();
        expect(loadFixtures()).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

"**setFixtures()**" test returns "Expected undefined to be defined."

```
describe("test set fixtures", function() {
    it("should be able to set fixtures", function() {
        // expect(setFixtures()).toBeDefined();
        expect(setFixtures()).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

Comment: Update: tried restarting. Same issue. Created a fresh directory with fresh jasmine testing suite and following the steps above. again same results.

Comment: update: did a "view > source" to see raw html and noticed that jasmine-jquery was loading before jquery. changed that in jasmine.yml so that jquery loaded first. Still not seeing loadFixtures or setFixtures.

Comment: update 3: took wamp out of the equation and ran from a different folder on a different drive. Still no change. I'm tapped out.

Comment: Update 4: I decided to try to load a fixture anyway and it worked! Inside a test i ran "loadFixtures("testfixture.html");" and "expect($(".container")).toExist();". This worked! I have a div with a class of container inside a file textfixture.html (/spec/javascripts/fixtures). So....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are not testing what you want to here. The functions `setFixtures` and `loadFixtures` do not have a return value. What that means is that when you call `setFixtures()` it will always return undefined. **You want to test that the functions are defined,  not the functions' return values.** Your tests should look like this instead:

```
it("should be able to set fixtures", function() {
    expect(setFixtures).toBeDefined(); // Notice I took out the ()
});
```

Comment: Damn! Something told me to go to bed, cuz coding tired always gets me into trouble! Thanks Andrew!